# Bad sound in Win8.1 after replacing a motherboard

Tags: windows-8.1, audio

I have replaced Asus P5Q with Asus P5Q Pro Turbo. It has a different HD Audio chip onboard so I have then uninstalled the old driver and installed a new one. Besides that, I also have a discrete audio card - Creative SB Audigy4. I have reinstalled its driver, too, as well as the drivers for Intel chipset.
Now I have a bad sound - one time in every few secs. It sound like a last sound you hear from the dynamics when you got a BSOD while your PC is playing a music or a movie. Its volume is dependent on the current sound level, so in the same track it may be loud, then quiet, then loud again etc. Both soundcards and all applications are affected. So I believe it's not a driver issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk which als runs on Win8.1), run WPRUI.exe,  load and check this profile inside WPRUI.exe (**Add Profiles**) https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rl4r784kvnhypf/Multimedia_WPRP.WPRP?dl=1 and click on **Start**. Now capture 1 minute of the audio issues. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file (+ NGENPDB fodler) into 1 zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: http://mir.cr/KIKF4HJZ. It's password protected. How can I send the password to you?

Comment: I have done that.

Comment: I've posted what I saw from the trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such glitches happen because of [DPC issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Procedure_Call). During execution of DPCs the whole system is blocked. The longer it takes you see video and audio glitches.

By dumping the statistics via `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\xperf.exe" -I RAISTLIN-WIN8.04-25-2017.01-10-00.etl -a dpcisr > dpc.txt` into a text I see this:

```
Total = 14514 for module iaStorA.sys
Elapsed Time, >        0 usecs AND <=        1 usecs,      0, or   0.00%
Elapsed Time, >        1 usecs AND <=        2 usecs,      0, or   0.00%
Elapsed Time, >        2 usecs AND <=        4 usecs,     16, or   0.11%
Elapsed Time, >        4 usecs AND <=        8 usecs,  12350, or  85.09%
Elapsed Time, >        8 usecs AND <=       16 usecs,   2067, or  14.24%
Elapsed Time, >       16 usecs AND <=       32 usecs,     80, or   0.55%
Elapsed Time, >    65536 usecs AND <=   131072 usecs,      0, or   0.00%
Elapsed Time, >   131072 usecs AND <=   262144 usecs,      1, or   0.01%
Total,                                                 14514

Total = 15903 for module storport.sys
Elapsed Time, >        0 usecs AND <=        1 usecs,     42, or   0.26%
Elapsed Time, >        1 usecs AND <=        2 usecs,    107, or   0.67%
Elapsed Time, >        2 usecs AND <=        4 usecs,   4783, or  30.08%
Elapsed Time, >        4 usecs AND <=        8 usecs,   2123, or  13.35%
Elapsed Time, >    65536 usecs AND <=   131072 usecs,      0, or   0.00%
Elapsed Time, >   131072 usecs AND <=   262144 usecs,     18, or   0.11%
Total,                                                 15903
```

Everything over 1024µs is bad. So storport.sys, iaStorA.sys are executing DPCs too long. This causes the glitch.

The `iaStorA.sys` is the `Intel® Rapid Storage Technology (Intel® RST)` driver. Your version is "15.2.0.1020". Try the [latest version 15.5.0.1051](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26730/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-?product=55005)

If this also doesn't fix it, install the standard SATA driver from Microsoft via device manager and look if this fixes it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes it was because of iaStorA.sys. But reinstalling IRST didn't help, no matter what I tried. So I fixed it another way: I connected my HDD to a discrete SATA controller, booted into the OS, uninstalled Intel RST, uninstall the device along with driver files in Device Manager and performed scan for hardware changes. Windows has found a new device and installed the standard driver. Then I connected my HDD back to the Intel SATA port. Now audio and video are being played with no issues. The only thing I don't like is that I lost Intel RST app. But it's the lesser evil.

Comment: for what have you used the  Intel RST app? Is this so important?

Comment: It is surely not until a RAID member is failed or has SMART problems. The question is how to know about it without IRST app. Also, it allows to schedule the verification.

Comment: When I got a SMART error, Windows showed in inbox dialog that my drive will fail: http://www.eassos.com/how-to/images/windows-detected-a-hard-disk-problem.png So Windows already does this.